# Как правильно объединять sql запросы через INNER JOIN?

Tags: php, sql

Смотрел на примеры и инструкции, так  не понял как правильно объединять запросы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запросы не объединяются через INNER JOIN. Через INNER JOIN объединяются таблицы в запросах. Чтобы объединить запросы, достаточно написать их друг за другом в одном скрипте.

Comment: Ой т.е таблицы объединить. Можете по подробные объяснить.
И еще это объединения стоит вообще делать для ускорение работы двидка?

Comment: Думаю, автор это и имел в виду) Тоже, кстати, интересна *ключевая разница* между JOIN и INNER JOIN и, например, идентично ли 
`SELECT * FROM a JOIN b [...]` и `SELECT * FROM b INNER JOIN a [...]`

Comment: Спасибо Вам, там где [...] мы указываем елементы таблицы к примеру b.id.....?

Comment: Так вам просто интуитивно-понятный пример запроса нужен?

Comment: Вроде да

Answer (score 1):

[Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Пример использования джойна

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM table_records AS T1
  INNER JOIN table_categories as T2 ON T1.parent_id=T2.id
  INNER JOIN table_properties as T3 ON T1.props_id=T3.id
  WHERE T1.id=1;
```

Т.о. получим запись с ID=1 из `table_records` и подгруженным к ней родительским элементом из `table_categories` и свойствами из `table_properties`.

Answer (score 0):

если вопрос понимать дословно, то вообще то запросы прекрасно соединяются как и обычные таблицы. 
пример на transact-sql

```sql
set nocount on

create table #n1(id int, n varchar(20))

create table #n2(id int, n varchar(20))

insert into #n1 values (1, 'таблица 1')

insert into #n2 values (1, 'таблица 2')

insert into #n2 values (2, 'таблица 2')


select *
from
    (select id, n from #n1) query1
    join 
        (select id, n from #n2) query2 on query2.id = query1.id


drop table #n1

drop table #n2
```